# Switch to visual studio prompt and execute command from inside batch file

Tags: batch, visual-studio

The command to open a Visual Studio 15 command prompt is:

```
%comspec% /K ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat""
```

What I want to do is have my batch file run and change to the visual studio version of the prompt and then execute a tool that is found along the visual studio tools path.

Right now I am trying:

```
%comspec% /K ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat""
ECHO Running XSD tool
xsd.exe my.xsd /c
```

The first line runs and then nothing. Is it possible to run subsequent commands?

Comment: `call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but that didn't work.

Comment: Did you try that as the first line of your batch file?

Comment: Yes I did do that

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the `vcvars32.bat` or `vcvars64.bat` instead. As of this writing these were in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build`.

Answering this as I ran into the same problem recently.